# Guessing Game Stochastic Optimization

Tags: probability, optimization, recreational-mathematics

This is part of another post I did, but I think it has interest in its own right:

Let $Y =\{X_{1},X_{2}...X_{N}\}$ be a set of $N$ random quantities with assocated set of distributions $F=\{F_{1},F_{2}...F_{N}\}$ and acceptable absolute errors $\epsilon = \{\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2}...\epsilon_{N}\}$. You are to develop a single-point prediction set $\hat X =\{\hat X_{1},\hat X_{2}...\hat X_{N}\}$ which contains one point from the possible range of each random quantity such that you maximize  $P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\textbf{1}_{|X_{i}-\hat X_{i}|\leq \epsilon_{i}}= N)$.

How should you select $\hat X =\{\hat X_{1},\hat X_{2}...\hat X_{N}\}$?

Comment: Are these random variables independent? I'll assume they are. For a given distribution $F_i$ you identify the point $x$ such that $\int_{x-\epsilon_i/2}^{x+\epsilon_i/2} F_i(x)$ is the largest. Choose that as $\hat{X}_i$.. Should work no?

Comment: Small correction: the $\epsilon$'s are absolute errors, so they are half-interval widths already. Also, the $F_{i}s$ are CDFs, the PDF would be $f_{i}(x)$. Your suggestion would imply that you choose $\hat X_{i}:\{f_{i}(\hat X_{i}-\epsilon) = f_{i}(\hat X_{i}+\epsilon)\}$ which will be some value of the density. That is what I have been thinking, since you are best off by simply finding the most probable intervals. Thanks for your input - I think that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer proposed by Sun will work. For the sum to equal N, there is only one point in the sample space of outcomes where this happens, and that is when each indicator variable is equal to 1. Therefore, to maximimze the probability, you need to maximize the probability that each indicator equals 1. Since each variable is independent, you are maximizing the product $\prod P(X_{i} \in x_i \pm \epsilon_i)$ where $P(X_{i} \in x_i \pm \epsilon_i)=\int_{x_i-\epsilon_i/2}^{x_i+\epsilon_i/2} F_i(x)$ The product is maximize by individually maximizing each factor to get the highest probability prediction.

Comment: I am the author. This post has been dormant for some time, but Sun's comment was useful. So I am declaring this question answered.

Comment: Dear Eupraxis: it's OK to answer your own questions, but we'd really prefer you make the answer substantial, and not just "that other comment works." Please consider editing this to recap the final solution you found, along with whatever you learned. Future users will appreciate your work :)

Comment: No problem. I've edited to make it clear why Sun's suggestion works.

Comment: Good job :) I deleted my comment, and I think people will probably support this solution now.